# Using CSV to plot parallel coordinates

Tags: python, csv, coordinates

I am trying to plot a parallel coordinates graph using data froma csv file. The csv file contains four columns. An example of the data is:

```
A, B, C, D
1, 2, 4, 8
5, 6, 1, 5
6, 5, 5, 10
```

I am getting an error that `No valid input arrays specified`. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Here is the code I have so far.

```
from vtk import *
import csv

FILENAME_PARA_COORD = "htc_2.csv"

# Load the paracoordinates table from CSV file
csv_source = vtkDelimitedTextReader()
csv_source.SetFieldDelimiterCharacters(",")
csv_source.DetectNumericColumnsOn()
csv_source.SetHaveHeaders(True)
csv_source.SetFileName(FILENAME_PARA_COORD)

# Set up the parallel coordinates Representation to be used in this view
rep = vtk.vtkParallelCoordinatesRepresentation()

# Plug your reader in here for your own data
if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:
   rep.SetInput(csv_source.GetOutput())

else:
   rep.SetInputConnection(csv_source.GetOutputPort())

# List all of the attribute arrays you want plotted in parallel coordinates
rep.SetInputArrayToProcess(0, 0, 0, 0, 'A')
rep.SetInputArrayToProcess(1, 0, 0, 0, 'B')
rep.SetInputArrayToProcess(2, 0, 0, 0, 'C')
rep.SetInputArrayToProcess(3, 0, 0, 0, 'D')

rep.SetUseCurves(0) # set to 1 to use smooth curves
rep.SetLineOpacity(0.5)

#Set up the Parallel Coordinates View and hook in the Representation
view = vtk.vtkParallelCoordinatesView()
view.SetRepresentation(rep)

# Inspect Mode determines whether your interactions manipulate the axes or
# select data
view.SetInspectMode(1) # VTK_INSPECT_SELECT_DATA =1

# Brush Mode determines the type of interaction you perform to select data
view.SetBrushModeToLasso()


# Brush Operator determines how each new selection interaction changes
# selected lines

view.SetBrushOperatorToReplace()

def ToggleInspectors(obj, event):
    # Define the callback routine which toggles between "Inspect Modes"
    if (view.GetInspectMode() == 0):
        view.SetInspectMode(1)
    else:
        view.SetInpsectMode(0)

# Hook up the callback to togle between inspect modes
# (manip axes & select data)
view.GetInteractor().AddObserver("UserEvent", ToggleInspectors)

# Set up render window
view.GetRenderWindow().SetSize(600, 300)
view.ResetCamera()
view.Render()

# Start interaction event loop
view.GetInteractor().Start()
```

Comment: I don't know the particularities of VTK - but shouldn't texts in a CSV be quoted? "A", "B", "C", "D"?

Comment: I have quoted the text but it still gives the same error

Comment: @jcoppens: I think CSV text only needs to be quoted when it contains delimiter characters.

Comment: @JoelCornett CSV has become a quicksand area... Every implementer seems to have his/her own ideas about it. You can now have every conceivable combination - you don't even have to use commas anymore :) As CSV is not a standard, you can do what your want, omit quoting completely, do it conditionally, or quote always. Some (eg. some U.S. gov) even quote numbers (floating point and integers!). I just asked if VTK wants quotes or not...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create lists for each column and then convert it into an array and plot:

Eg:

```
A = ['1','2','3','4']     #list of strings
A = [int(i) for i in A]   #to 
O/p A = [1,2,3,4]         #list of integers
```

Then you can plot parallel coordinates.